# Como ler um arquivo em C mas para não contar com o cabeçalho no contador?

Tags: c

ARQUIVO

A PRIMEIRA LINHA É O CABEÇALHO QUE QUERO DESCONSIDERAR.
Para que o contador "num" não comece a contar a partir do CABEÇALHO

Empresa  Sobre Nome Funcao

EmpresaA Bedecs Anna Proprietario

EmpresaB Gratacos Antonio Proprietario

EmpresaC Axen Thomas Compras

EmpresaD Lee Christina Gerente

EmpresaE ODonnell Martin Proprietario

EmpresaF PrezOlaeta Francisco Gerente

EmpresaG Xie Ming-Yang Proprietario

EmpresaH Andersen Elizabeth Representante

EmpresaI Mortensen Sven Compras

EmpresaJ Wacker Roland Compras

EmpresaK Krschne Peter Gerente

EmpresaL Edwards John Gerente

EmpresaM Ludick Andre Representante

EmpresaN Grilo Carlos Representante

EmpresaO Kupkova Helena Gerente

EmpresaP Goldschmidt Daniel Representante

EmpresaQ Bagel Jean Proprietario

EmpresaR Autier Catherine Representante

EmpresaS Eggerer Alexander Contabilidade

EmpresaT Li George Gerente

EmpresaU Tham Bernard Gerente

EmpresaV Ramos Luciana Assistente

EmpresaW Entin Michael Gerente

EmpresaX Hasselberg Jonas Proprietario

EmpresaY Rodman John Gerente

EmpresaZ Liu Run Assistente

EmpresaAA Toh Karen Gerente

EmpresaBB Raghav Amritansh Gerente

EmpresaCC Lee Soo Gerente

CÓDIGO FONTE ABAIXO

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main(){
FILE * input_text, *output_text;
char line[1024];
char * last;
int num = 0;
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
    if((input_text = fopen("entrada03.txt","r")) == NULL)
        printf("\n[ERRO]Travou o Nintendo!\n");
    else
        printf("\n[SUCESSO]Sucesso ao abrir o arquivo!\n\n");
    printf("\n\nImprimindo a saida\n\n");
    sleep(2);
    output_text = fopen("saida02.txt","w");

            while(!feof(input_text)){
                fgets(line, 1024, input_text);
                    last = strtok(line, "\n");                                  //"last" recebe variável "line" até o delimitador "\n"
                        while(last != NULL){                                    //Se last não for "NULL" executa essa
                            printf("%d: %s\n",num, last);
                                last = strtok(NULL, "\n");                      //Se last for "NULL" até o delimitador "\n"
                                fprintf(output_text,"%d: %s\n", num, line);
                        }
                    num++;
            }
fclose(input_text);
fclose(output_text);
printf("\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veja se é isso que gostaria que fosse feito:

O que alterei foi incluir o if(num != 0) para apresentar na tela e depois gravar no seu arquivo, dessa forma ele lê/escreve tudo que for diferente da linha 0;

Outro ponto, tome cuidado porque você esta utilizando aplicações de C++ em seu código, desde que funcione, mas não é muito elegante...

Espero que tenha ajudado. Abraços!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
FILE * input_text, *output_text;
char line[1024];
char * last;
int num = 0;
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
    if((input_text = fopen("entrada03.txt","r")) == NULL)
        printf("\n[ERRO]Travou o Nintendo!\n");
    else
        printf("\n[SUCESSO]Sucesso ao abrir o arquivo!\n\n");
    printf("\n\nImprimindo a saida\n\n");
    sleep(2);
    output_text = fopen("saida02.txt","w");

        while(!feof(input_text)){
            fgets(line, 1024, input_text);
                last = strtok(line, "\n");                                  //"last" recebe variável "line" até o delimitador "\n"
                    while(last != NULL){                                    //Se last não for "NULL" executa essa
                        if(num != 0)
                        printf("%d: %s\n",num, last);
                            last = strtok(NULL, "\n");                      //Se last for "NULL" até o delimitador "\n"
                            if(num != 0)                      
                            fprintf(output_text,"%d: %s\n", num, line);
                    }
                num++;
        }
fclose(input_text);
fclose(output_text);
printf("\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: bom ok, era isso ai mesmo. obrigado, um simples detalhe muda tudo.

Comment: Ótimo que serviu. Abraços!